# How can I pull products according to categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get products according to categories by using Laravel Relationships.

Category names are stored in **terms** table and in products table, I have added **term_id** column.

Here is my terms table [image]

And here is my **product** table
[image]

This is what I have done so far in **Term** model-

```
public function products(){

    return $this->hasMany('shopist\Models\Product');

}
```

And in my Controller-

```
    public function products()
        {

            $pro = term::where('term_id',2)->first();
            $pro->products;

        }
```

But I am not getting any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct your relation in **Term** model by following this-

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('shopist\Models\Product', 'term_id', 'term_id'); // foreign key and local key should be defined
}
```

You have to define the foreign key and local key in the **relation** because you are not following the recommended laravel conventions for the primary key column names.

So it's necessary to tell the method that what keys need to be used as a relation.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public function products()
        {

            return Term::where('term_id',2)->first();

        }
```

or if you have a Product Model

```
public function products()
    {

        return Product::where('term_id',2)->first();

    }
```